# How to avoid SQL Injection attacks in SSRS of SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: ssrs-2008, validation

I need to prevent the user from entering the characters that may result in malfunctioning of the Database. I'm using stored procedures for the reports. I need to validate the the textbox parameter for the purpose. Any one please guide me on how can i do this.

Comment: Just **always** use **parametrized queries** and **NEVER** concatenate together your own SQL statements with user input and execute them....

Comment: See also: [MSDN How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) or [SQL Injection Attacks and Some Tips on How to Prevent Them](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev) or just **google** for `prevent SQL injection attacks` and you'll get literally **thousands** of hits showing you how to do it....

Comment: @marc_s, I'm using parametrized queries and not using concatenations in my Stored procedures. So do you mean using the textbox in SSRS to get parameter values won't be vulnerable.

Comment: If you only use those user inputs as **parameter values** - then no, there's no SQL injection risk

Answer (score 1):

- Restrict access to your report where possible
- Use a limited SQL Server reporting account that only has restricted read only access to the tables it requires
- Where sensible, limit user selection to drop down lists
- If you wrapping the report inside a programming language like c#, you can use Validators on the input and parameterised queries.
- If you passing ssrs parameters directly to your stored procedure and worried that text injection may occur, pass the parameter for unexpected patterns within SQL prior to utilising  i.e. a user id that has the expected format of *"A3290RE"* can be checked for spaces with CONTAINS and verified for length with LEN to prevent a user entereing *"A3290RE ' or name like '%a%"*.